# running a new language in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction

our goal s to execute file with help of a jar file.load a jar file and include it during compilation . Using wizard , set dependencies and with those try to execute file
with command

```
java -cp "jar file " file name
```

we  have to programatically excute the above command

Comment: do you think ANT could help on that?

Comment: we have our own compiler .. we are creating a development tool for that language..and I don't know how ant will work..

Comment: ANT is a build/automation tool that is integrated to eclipse. If you want to add some step in the middle of your compilation process, I think this is an option for you. But I am not sure if your question has all the information needed to be properly answered.

Comment: actually we are doing intern-ship in one company and our guide only say this much to us. so we only know these things.and we are creating something like JDT.

Comment: it's a long way to go :-)

Comment: we do the rest already,, now in the last part.. running the code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52555/discussion-between-pathuz-and-leo)